# I need a way to launch my .swf file and have it always stay as the bottom window on windows 7

Tags: actionscript-3, windows-7, flash

I am trying to make an swf file that will act as the wallpaper for my computer. The right now I have two issues that I am unable to resolve.

1. The window needs to always stay at the bottom of my desktop, below rocketDock and the taskbar.
2. I want to disable the swf from minimizing as I frequently use the Windows Key + M shortcut to reach my desktop.

I know there must be an AS3 command that can set the window to be always on bottom. Either that or some kind of property I can change about the swf file in windows.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you're likely to be able to do this with AS3 it's not well suited to created desktop apps that tightly integrate with a particular OS rather it's meant more as a means to write code that can be run on any system.  My guess is you'll have more luck using C# and WPF rather than Flex for accomplishing this.  In terms of the keyboard shortcut normally you can stop propagation of events to stop Flex/Flash from doing it's default behavior, however in this case you're trying to block a global hotkey so I doubt if this will be possible through AS3 code in any way (you may be able to listen for the minimize then re-maximize but without the ability to put the window behind the icons I don't know that it matters).

For relevant things in AS3 you would want to look at NativeWindow and related classes, but I haven't come across anything in taking a quick look and have never heard of such a thing in AS3: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/NativeWindowInitOptions.html